# Using an Array to Check for String Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am building a clock that updates every second using `setInterval` and `new Date()`. But, I am having trouble changing one digit numbers to two digit numbers using and array. For example, I want 5 hours, 9 minutes, and 5 seconds to display as 05:09:05 (adding zeros to the front of one digit numbers). For some odd reason, my array with a for loop and if statement doesn't do this. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* Variables */
  var d;
  var h;
  var m;
  var s;
  var arr;
  
  setInterval(function(){
    /* Get time every second */
    d = new Date();
    h = d.getHours();
    m = d.getMinutes();
    s = d.getSeconds();
    
    /* Check for character count */
    arr = [h, m, s];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].toString().length == 1) {
        arr[i] = '0' + arr[i];
      }
    }
    
    $('h1').html(h + ':' + m + ':' + s)
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>12:00:00</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to output the array instead of the individual *h*, *m*, *s*.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* Variables */
  var d;
  var h;
  var m;
  var s;
  var arr;
  
  setInterval(function(){
    /* Get time every second */
    d = new Date();
    h = d.getHours();
    m = d.getMinutes();
    s = d.getSeconds();
    
    /* Check for character count */
    arr = [h, m, s];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].toString().length == 1) {
        arr[i] = '0' + arr[i];
      }
    }
    
    //$('h1').html(arr[0] + ':' + arr[1] + ':' + arr[2])
    $('h1').html(arr.join(':')) // join instead of outputting individually
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>12:00:00</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put the strings in the array, it doesn't directly put the object, it puts a copy of the object.

Then when it is displayed, instead of using directly `h`, `m` and `s` (the original objects that have not been modified) it displays the items from the array (`arr[0]`, ...).

I hope it helps.